# What's the difference between using the reflections when fighting in Calm?

Tags: torment-tides-of-numenera

When you are fighting in the Calm, sometimes (or always, I don't. It's my first play-thru) you can call your reflections to help you during the fight.

[image: option to get reflections on a fight]

Are there any differences between fighting alone or with your party reflections?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I noticed between playing **this screen/quest** alone or with the party is a bonus of +3XP. Don't know about other quests in the Labyrinth.

For this quest (*Infestation*) with enough buffers and good evasion, it's really easy to finish alone. Don't fight. Just activate the machines to attract the fragments. The first one will be more difficult because you will have to deal with 2 at the same time. But the third one will be easier because it will be one on one.